Wi-Fi not working on Xubuntu 23.10 live CD
I booted Xubuntu 23.10 on my iMac (27-inch, Mid 2011) using the "Windows" option. However, after the boot process is complete, I don't see an option for Wi-Fi. I tried going to the advanced network settings and tried to configure the system to connect to my home network, but I can't create a Wi-Fi connection. Is this because Xubuntu can't detect my iMac's Wi-Fi hardware? I need to connect to Wi-Fi in order to install updates during installation.

Yes, because Apple x Broadcom WLAN network cards are provided with proprietary drivers. You should enable these drivers before running an installer.
